# Using parametrized parameters WITH sqlcommandbuilder [no dataadapter]

Tags: c#, sql, prepared-statement

I am trying to use a parametrized query which takes 2 column names and a table name and retrieves the data from a sql server DB.

The problem is it is not possible to parametrize the table name so i found a solution using a sqlcommandbuilder.quoteIdentifer(tablename) and this bit works...but apparently they don't play nice together.

I get exception containing a single word which is the column name
If i put the column name by hand it works.

What is wrong here?

```
    public List<ItemsWithDescription> GetItemsFromDB(string name, string desc, string tableName)
    {
        List<ItemsWithDescription> items = new List<ItemsWithDescription>();
        try
        {
            Status = 1;
            SqlCommandBuilder builder = new SqlCommandBuilder();
            cmd = new SqlCommand("Select @Name, @Desc from "+ builder.QuoteIdentifier(tableName), conn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", name);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Desc", desc);
            using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    items.Add(new ItemsWithDescription(dr[name].ToString(), dr[name].ToString() + " | " + dr[desc].ToString()));                        
                }
            }
            items.Sort((x, y) => string.Compare(x.Item, y.Item));
        }
        catch
        {
            Status = -1;
        }
        return items;
    }
```

Edit:
This works but I would prefer to know why both can't be used together:

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("Select" +
builder.QuoteIdentifier(name) + "," + 
builder.QuoteIdentifier(desc) + "from " +
builder.QuoteIdentifier(tableName), conn);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't parameterize column names. You can't do that in *regular* SQL actually.

What you need is  [`Dynamic SQL`](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html).

> If you follow the various newsgroups on Microsoft SQL Server, you
>   often see people asking why they can't do:

```
SELECT * FROM @tablename
SELECT @colname FROM tbl
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE x IN (@list)
```

> For all three examples you can expect someone to answer Use dynamic
>   SQL and give a quick example on how to do it. Unfortunately, for all
>   three examples above, dynamic SQL is a poor solution. On the other
>   hand, there are situations where dynamic SQL is the best or only way
>   to go.

Also take a look [`Table-Valued Parameters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx) if you use SQL Server 2008 and above.

Comment: Is Dynamic SQL prone to attacks?

Comment: @AngelicCore I don't think so.. http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#SQL_injection